# Elastic Search Match_phrase not giving deterministic result

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-map-reduce, elasticsearch-plugin, match-phrase

I have defined mapping in following way.

```
PUT _template/name
"mappings": {
    "_default_": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer" : "synonyms_expand",
            "index" : "analyzed",
            "position_offset_gap": 100
        },
    }
}
```

I am executing following query

```
GET _search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should" : [{
                "match_phrase": {
                    "petitioners.name": {
                        "query": "onkar kundargi "
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

still it is giving result for only onkar. Not evaluting complete string for search. Can anybody  help me ???